# Origin of land-lottery system

Tags: economy, middle-east, agriculture, political-economy

A [report from 1894](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Palestine_Exploration_Fund_-_Quarterly_Statement_for_1894/Land_Tenure_in_Palestine) describes the Musha'a land tenure system in the Arab villages of Palestine: the agricultural lands of the village are considered common property, and they are divided each year among the villagers, by drawing lots.

Land division by lots was already described in the Bible (Numbers 26, Joshua 18), however, this was a one-time division, after which each citizen kept his lot for good.

What are the earliest known accounts of the Musha'a system? How did this system originate?

Comment: periodic redistribution of land in peasant villages was used in many parts of Europe as well. It was not only a middle eastern thing.